# В чем разница между сайтом и веб-приложением?

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Не могу понять чем отличается веб-сайт и веб-приложение. Хотелось бы узнать ответ на этот вопрос, в интернете много каши и однозначного ответа я не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сайт это то что тупо выдает информацию. Веб приложение то что позволяет управлять этой информацией, создавать новую и тд.
Сайты:

1. Сайты визитки
2. Лендинги
3. Интернет магазины
4. Прочие типовые интернет ресурсы

Web-приложения:

1. Личные кабинеты
2. Интернет ресурсы имеющие уникальный функционал
3. Все что заточено на создание и управление чем либо

   Google maps, ютуб, личный кабинет МТС -  веб-приложения. Википедия сайт, сайт мтс, лента ру - это сайты

Comment: А поисковики? Они же тупо выдают информацию...

Comment: @АндрейМиронов Они не тупо выдают информацию, они анализируют ввод и формируют вывод не тупо первое попавшиеся из базы данных

Answer (score 1):

Сайт - это примитивное (**статичное**) веб-приложение. Например страница с текстом "hallo world" **технически** может назваться сайтом, если у неё есть домен, IP и её можно открыть в инете. Если на сайте есть **интерактивность**, то есть он **не статичен**, то **технически** это можно назвать веб-приложением. К примеру, если вышеупомянутый текст откликается на нажатие мышки, каким-нибудь исполнением, то **технически** это уже приложение. Поэтому, на сегодняшний день практически любая страница является приложением.

В то же время, как отмечено [Geri4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215147/geri4), всевозможные информационные ресурсы, магазины, лендинги нами **подразумеваются** как сайты, тогда как поисковики, карты, и заточенные под узкую специализацию ресурсы **рассматриваются** нами как веб-приложения.

Comment: те сайт может быть веб приложением, но веб приложение не всегда обязано быть сайтом, верно?

Comment: Приложения, вроде paint.net, sketchup и другие, которые работают в ОС не являются веб, но называются приложениями той ОС в которой они исполняются. Например андроид приложения, виндовс приложения. Приложения, которые разработаны для работы в нескольких ОС либо без ОС называют автономными приложениями. Понятие "веб" относится к приложениям, которые исполняются в браузере. Поэтому, опять же, технически все приложения являются сайтами. Вы можете рассматривать слово  "сайт" просто как устаревшее, либо разделять эти понятия по насыщению интерактивностью, или по "заточенности" как отмечалось ранее.

Comment: сайт == веб-приложение //true, потому что одинаковая среда выполнения (браузер).  Сайт !== веб-приложение //true, потому что он не обладает интерактивностью.